# How to debug and step into custom language sources transpiled to C++?

Tags: c++, debugging, transpiler

I would like to use a custom preprocessor language along with C++. My sources would be first transpiled to valid C++ with my custom transpiler, then compiled with a regular C++ compiler. Example:

```sh
my_transpiler -o source_gen.cpp source.mycpp
g++ -o myapp source_gen.cpp
```

In that scenario, the debug information generated are associated with the *source_gen.cpp* file. So I could debug and step into *source_gen.cpp*. But what if I want to step into the original source file *source.mycpp* ?

Does debugger as *gdb* or *visual studio*, or compiler as *clang*, *gcc*, or *msvc* provide mechanisms to map debug information to the original source file?

Comment: I think you are looking for the `#line` preprocessor directive: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html

Comment: Here's the documentation for Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-line-directive-c-cpp?view=vs-2019

Comment: Unless your transpiler provides that information, I don't think you can.

Comment: I think it would be a better idea to make transpiler into llvm language and try to utilize lldb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was hinted in a comment to the question, the usual approach to this issue is the `#line` directive. In particular,

```
# line digit-sequence " s-char-sequenceopt " new-line
```

Your transpiler should put this directive for each source line in the original file into the generated file:

```
#line 3 "source.mycpp"
```

If your C++ compiler generates debug information based on these directives (the ones I've used do), when you step into the code you'll step into the appropriate spot in source.mycpp.

Comment: if instead of a preprocessing language I was using a completely different language, would it be possible to map symbol name and type with a similar method?

Comment: @Dragnalith -- yes. The experience that I alluded to elliptically was with a Java to C translator.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generation `xxx_gen.cpp` files, you can create an additional directory for the generated files and keep the file name for the files. If you have a directory hierarchy, you also can duplicate the whole tree.

After compilation you can in gdb [set the source path](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html). This will result in finding the "original" files.

The information will only by valid, if each source line will only generate a single target line. :-)